# ResourceLoader in shared assembly

Tags: c#, win-universal-app

Class Library A

- Strings

  - en-US

    - Resources.resw
  - zh-CN

    - Resources.resw
- Application

  - Views

    - ViewA.xaml

So I have a View, `ViewA` that I need to manually load localized strings from. However, whenever I do this, I receive an empty string.

I have tried:

```
var loader = ResourceLoader.GetForCurrentView();
var myLocalizedText = loader.GetString("Foo");
```

and

```
var loader = new ResourceLoader();
var myLocalizedText = loader.GetString("Foo");
```

The variable `myLocalizedText` is always an empty string.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to reproduce your issue, however I just got `ResourceMap Not Found.` exception when using `ResourceLoader.GetForCurrentView()` or `new ResourceLoader()`.

If we want to construct a resource loader for resources from a library package, we need use [`ResourceLoader.GetForCurrentView(String)` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn297382.aspx) or [`ResourceLoader.ResourceLoader(String)` constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br206021.aspx). Here the `String` is the resource identifier of the [ResourceMap](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.resources.core.resourcemap.aspx) that the new resource loader uses for unqualified resource references.

> Components or library files are typically added into a subfolder of the package they are included in during the build process, similar to their string resources. Their resource identifier usually takes the following form:
>
> *ClassLibraryOrAssemblyName/ResourceFileName/StringName*

So for your case, we can use following code to load localized strings:

```
var loader = ResourceLoader.GetForCurrentView("ClassLibraryA/Resources");
var myLocalizedText = loader.GetString("Foo");
```

For more information, please see: [Loading strings from libraries or controls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh965323.aspx#loading_strings_from_libraries_or_controls) and **scenario 6** in [Application resources and localization sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/ApplicationResources).

Besides, please note that for a UWP app, it's better to use `GetForCurrentView(String)` method:

> [ResourceLoader(String) may be altered or unavailable for releases after Windows 8.1. Instead, use **GetForCurrentView(String)**.]

Also if you want to add Chinese language, you'd better use **`zh-Hans`** instead of **`zh-CN`**:

> Include script when there is no suppress script value defined for the language. See the [IANA subtag registry](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?linkid=227303) for language tag details. For example, use zh-Hant, zh-Hant-TW, or zh-Hans, and not zh-CN or zh-TW.

For more information see: [Qualify resources with their language](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh967761.aspx#qualify_resources_with_their_language.).

Comment: I think I figured out my issue. It was that when you reference resource strings with a "." period in them you need to replace the "." with a "/". Very confusing!